# Disable cache for a @vercel/postgres query in NextJS using the app router

Tags: caching, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

The code in my `app/page.tsx` looks like this

```js
import AddTodo from "./components/add-todo";
import Todo from "./components/todo";
import { sql } from "@vercel/postgres";

export default async function Home() {
  let data = await sql`SELECT * FROM todos`;
  const { rows: todos } = data;

  return (
    <main>
      <AddTodo />
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <Todo key={todo.id} id={todo.id} title={todo.text} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </main>
  );
}
```

When I change the data in the database manually and reload the index page, it displays an outdated list of todos. I have to refresh with disabled cache in order to see the updated list. How can I make NextJS regenerate this page on every request instead of returning a cached version?

With the pages router I would use `getServerSideProps` and if I was using `fetch` in the app router, I would use it with `cache: 'no-store'`. But how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

One solution I just found is to force the page to be dynamic using:

```js
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';
```

This leads to the desired behavior. But maybe there is a more implicit solution out there.

Comment: You placed that on the page or on some component? Not working for me on NextJs 14

Comment: Worked for me, you have to add it to the page where you are doing the request.

Comment: not working neither in next 14

Comment: @AnisSmail - See my answer below, I suspect you might be handling this client-side, and therefor need to refresh the client cache as well.

Comment: @Vinny - See my answer below, I suspect you might be handling this client-side, and therefor need to refresh the client cache as well.

Answer (score 1):

As of NextJS 14, you can use the `unstable_noStore()` function to opt-out of cache at a component level. As stated in the docs, it's preferred over using `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';` as it gives you more control.

You use it simply by adding `unstable_noStore()` to the component you don't want to be cached. Just make sure you import the function also: `import { unstable_noStore } from 'next/cache';`.

**Client-Side**
In cases where you're doing data with client-side, you may also need to use `useRouter().refresh()` to refresh the router cache.
Again, make sure you import it: `import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";`.

If you are calling `useRouter()` more than once, whack it in a `const router = useRouter()`.

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/unstable_noStore